# VGA DAC circuit

Tags: dac, vga

I have a PIC mcu which I am trying to drive a VGA monitor with.I am using a simple resistor DAC. I was trying to show a simple white screen but it only shows some shade of grey/black. I measured the voltage at the red, green, and blue pins and I read 0.74 volts in each. I know the voltage should be in 0-0.7 V range, is it possible my monitor behaves unexpectedly when the voltage exceeds 0.7 V?

This is the DAC circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFtS69.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Which kind of VGA monitor? Old CRT or modern LCD?Do you blank the video to black between lines so the monitor gets a proper blanking period? How do you send H/V sync signals? Is the ground connected?

Comment: Did you send the color data without HSYNC and VSYNC?